# How to disable git aware zsh theme on folders that dont have a .git/

Tags: git, shell, plugins, zsh

I'm really happy with the git plugin that comes with oh-my-zsh, but i haven't figure out how to add a function to check for a initialized git repo (i.e. check for .git folder) and don't display the branch name or status if it returns false. This is a great plug in but it does slow down the shell and I'd like to have it off on the other 90% of the folders...

```
# get the name of the branch we are on
function git_prompt_info() {
  ref=$(git symbolic-ref HEAD 2> /dev/null) || return
  echo "$ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_PREFIX${ref#refs/heads/}$(parse_git_dirty)$ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_SUFFIX"
}


# Checks if working tree is dirty
parse_git_dirty() {
  local SUBMODULE_SYNTAX=''
  if [[ $POST_1_7_2_GIT -gt 0 ]]; then
        SUBMODULE_SYNTAX="--ignore-submodules=dirty"
  fi
  if [[ -n $(git status -s ${SUBMODULE_SYNTAX}  2> /dev/null) ]]; then
    echo "$ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_DIRTY"
  else
    echo "$ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_CLEAN"
  fi
}


# Checks if there are commits ahead from remote
function git_prompt_ahead() {
  if $(echo "$(git log origin/$(current_branch)..HEAD 2> /dev/null)" | grep '^commit' &> /dev/null); then
    echo "$ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_AHEAD"
  fi
}

# Formats prompt string for current git commit short SHA
function git_prompt_short_sha() {
  SHA=$(git rev-parse --short HEAD 2> /dev/null) && echo "$ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_SHA_BEFORE$SHA$ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_SHA_AFTER"
}

# Formats prompt string for current git commit long SHA
function git_prompt_long_sha() {
  SHA=$(git rev-parse HEAD 2> /dev/null) && echo "$ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_SHA_BEFORE$SHA$ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_SHA_AFTER"
}

# Get the status of the working tree
git_prompt_status() {
  INDEX=$(git status --porcelain 2> /dev/null)
  STATUS=""
  if $(echo "$INDEX" | grep '^?? ' &> /dev/null); then
    STATUS="$ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_UNTRACKED$STATUS"
  fi
  if $(echo "$INDEX" | grep '^A  ' &> /dev/null); then
    STATUS="$ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_ADDED$STATUS"
  elif $(echo "$INDEX" | grep '^M  ' &> /dev/null); then
    STATUS="$ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_ADDED$STATUS"
  fi
  if $(echo "$INDEX" | grep '^ M ' &> /dev/null); then
    STATUS="$ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_MODIFIED$STATUS"
  elif $(echo "$INDEX" | grep '^AM ' &> /dev/null); then
    STATUS="$ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_MODIFIED$STATUS"
  elif $(echo "$INDEX" | grep '^ T ' &> /dev/null); then
    STATUS="$ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_MODIFIED$STATUS"
  fi
  if $(echo "$INDEX" | grep '^R  ' &> /dev/null); then
    STATUS="$ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_RENAMED$STATUS"
  fi
  if $(echo "$INDEX" | grep '^ D ' &> /dev/null); then
    STATUS="$ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_DELETED$STATUS"
  elif $(echo "$INDEX" | grep '^AD ' &> /dev/null); then
    STATUS="$ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_DELETED$STATUS"
  fi
  if $(echo "$INDEX" | grep '^UU ' &> /dev/null); then
    STATUS="$ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_UNMERGED$STATUS"
  fi
  echo $STATUS
}

#compare the provided version of git to the version installed and on path
#prints 1 if input version <= installed version
#prints -1 otherwise 
function git_compare_version() {
  local INPUT_GIT_VERSION=$1;
  local INSTALLED_GIT_VERSION
  INPUT_GIT_VERSION=(${(s/./)INPUT_GIT_VERSION});
  INSTALLED_GIT_VERSION=($(git --version));
  INSTALLED_GIT_VERSION=(${(s/./)INSTALLED_GIT_VERSION[3]});

  for i in {1..3}; do
    if [[ $INSTALLED_GIT_VERSION[$i] -lt $INPUT_GIT_VERSION[$i] ]]; then
      echo -1
      return 0
    fi
  done
  echo 1
}

#this is unlikely to change so make it all statically assigned
POST_1_7_2_GIT=$(git_compare_version "1.7.2")
#clean up the namespace slightly by removing the checker function
unset -f git_compare_version
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write an if statement that goes out of the script if you aren't in a git folder.

```
if [ ! -d $PWD/.git ]; then
    exit # or your exit function, like return
```

Comment: I wrapped the contents of the `git_prompt_info` function in `lib/git.zsh` with `if [ -d "$PWD/.git ]; then`.

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative framework that updates the git information only when necessary, i.e. when you change directory (`chpwd` hook) or when you run the `git` command: [zsh-git-prompt](https://github.com/simonair/zsh-git-prompt). Note that it requires Python. It should not be hard to integrate this into oh-my-zsh as a plugin.

The key change I made in my fork is to allow you to set the directory containing the plugin's files (`__GIT_PROMPT_DIR`).